# Jquery: Selector can't find class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm trying to advance the Jquery-autcomplete function. I want Jquery-autocomplete to create new rows in a table. That works so far. But I want Jquery to add a delete-button. So the user is able to delete one of his added items.

```
    $(document).ready(
function() {


//create an new <tr> <td> in #log   
    function log( message ) {
        $("<tr> <td>"  + message + "<input class='Entf' type='button' value ='Entfernen' />" + "</td></tr>").appendTo("#log");
        $( "#log" ).attr( "scrollTop", 0 );}


// get the values from a json-source
        $( "#REMOTE" ).autocomplete({
            source: "json.php",
            minLength: 0,
            select: function( event, ui ) {
                log( ui.item ?
                    ui.item.value + " aka " + ui.item.id :
                    "Nothing selected, input was " + this.value );}
});


// this is just a test if jquery recognizes the click       
         $('.Entf').click(function(event){
     alert("Thanks for visiting!");
   });
    });
```

But jQuery doesen't recognize the click of the element it created. To check fpr erros, I placed one row in the html. This button works. But when I add a row via Jquery, the added button deon't work. Here an example from firebug:

```
<table id="log" border="0" width="400">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>
test
<input class="Entf" type="button" value="Entfernen">         //this one workes fine. it comes from the original html
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
daniel aka 121
<input class="Entf" type="button" value="Entfernen">     //this one doesn't work. it's the one that was added by Jquery
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Any ideas?

Thank you! Exuse my english :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use [jQuery live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/):

```
$('.Entf').live('click',function(event){
     alert("Thanks for visiting!");
   });
```

using live enables jQuery use callbacks on selectors that are dynamically created by javascript

Comment: @brill - .and to that end on stackoverflow you select a correct answer to be 'accepted' that way if you have future Q's more people will be glad to help ^_^

Comment: 'live' was replaced by 'delegate', which was then replaced with 'on'

Answer (score 2):

Because the element is getting created after the handlers are bound, it's not registering. You need something like this:

```
$("body").delegate(".Entf", "click", function() { //function here });
```

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) in jQuery 1.7+

```
$(document).on("click",".Entf",function(event){
     alert("Thanks for visiting!");
   });
```

Use jQuery [delegate()](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) in jQuery 1.4.3+:

```
$(document).delegate(".Entf", "click", function(event){
     alert("Thanks for visiting!");
   });
```

And use jQuery live() in jQuery 1.3:

```
$('.Entf').live('click',function(event){
     alert("Thanks for visiting!");
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

When you have generated content, you need to bind the button, ie, after you have generated the content, do:

```
 $('.Entf').click(function(event){
     alert("Thanks for visiting!");
});
```

again.

**Edit:** As pointed out by Neal, be careful when doing it this method.  The reason as that it will bind to ALL .Entf elements, not just the new ones, causing multiple click events.  See http://jsfiddle.net/R9Kb4/2/ for an example of how to create and bind things without having to deal with live() or with multiple binding.

Comment: this is untrue, just use jQuery and `live()`

Comment: uh... that's a little harsh, buddy.  Rebinding the click the way I mentioned DOES work... you never even tried it.  Please think before you downvote!

Comment: @Levi, yes you can rebind, but it is not the best thing to do

Comment: @Neal What's the point of downvoting something for being 'untrue' when it does in fact work?  Anyway, congrats on getting upvoted, Neal.

Comment: @Levi, you can see from this example that the click gets multiplied exponentially on prev elements: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/HHBQL/

Comment: @Levi, im not trying to say you are wrong, look at my example and u will see

Comment: @Neal I'm not getting the results you imply should be there.  However, I do know what you are talking about. I just ask that if you are going to downvote something, at least write something that is true.  My way does work, if you downvote it, at least say WHY, ie, the muliplicity example rather than claiming it to be false when indeed it is not.

Comment: @Levi, so yes, i am not being 'harsh' sorry if it seems that way.

Comment: @Levi i better updated my example without the use of the console to show you: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/HHBQL/3/

Comment: @Neal What is actually happening is that you literally ARE binding things multiple times.  This happens because you don't unbind the previous ones.  In the case of generated code, it has no previously bound events.  Anyway, again, my point with these comments is basically this: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#behonest . Say specifically what is wrong, not simply that it is untrue (because let's face it, it isn't untrue, it's just not the best solution).  :)  **Edit:** basically... whenever you are binding the .class, it rebinds ALL of them, not just the new one.

Comment: @Levi okey dokey. you never say in your answer to unbind :-p

Comment: @Neal http://jsfiddle.net/R9Kb4/1/ See that example.  That's how I usually append things because it let's me use jQuery the newly created element and not the thing I'm appending to.  Oh, and thanks for the un-downvoting ;)

Comment: @Levi , no problem. ill look @ the fiddle now

Comment: @Levi, that fiddle does not load.

Comment: @Neal Hmm... it is for me.  Odd. In html it has `<div id='click'>Click me</div>` and for JavaScript: `$('#click').click(function(){
    $('<div>',
      {
        class:'newOne',
        text: 'hi there'
      }
     ).appendTo('#click').click(function(){
        console.log(this)
     });
});`

Comment: @Levi, that one still works, still seems quite exponential :-p

Comment: @Neal . . .  it works fine for me. Try http://jsfiddle.net/R9Kb4/2/ (It's the same thing, I just reordered the click before the appendTo for clarity's sake) You are sure that doesn't load?  And you are sure it exponentially binds them?  Because mine is just fine... When I click on Click Me, it appends only 1, and when I click on appended text, it only appends one.

Comment: @Levi, ahhh it works, i did not know that it was ur intention for it to append to the bottom with the new items. ok. i never used `appendTo()`