# jQuery won't target a class with multiple classes

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am adding a class to an element on page load with this

```
(function($) {
 $(document).ready(function() {
  $('.navigation').addClass('slideIn');
});
```

However, when I add the class, this code doesn't work:

```
$(function() {
  $('.navigation.slideIn ul li.home a').addClass('active');
});
```

But, if I don't add the class and I use:

```
$(function() {
  $('.navigation ul li.home a').addClass('active');
});
```

it works perfectly fine. Why is it not targeting it correctly?

Comment: there's nothing wrong (beside some missing `});`). Please create a [mcve]

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan In JSFiddle?

Answer (score 0):

Based this question and answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/15402118/5333612, It's look your class is added dynamically with javascript (jQuery).

But, why don't you add the active class directly on page ready?

```
(function($) {
 $(document).ready(function() {
  $('.navigation').addClass('slideIn'); // You can add this class too
  $('.navigation').addClass('active');
});
```